# NoMethodError: undefined method `sql_for_on_duplicate_key_update' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter:0xb73ddf8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord-import

I have a Rails application, recently I changed my database from MySql to PostgreSql, from then onwards active-records `import` method `:on_duplicate_key_update` is throwing an error.

```
def import_of_products(import_links)
  Product.import import_links, :on_duplicate_key_update => [:ad_id]   
end
```

The error showing is,

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `sql_for_on_duplicate_key_update' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter:0xab19f90>
from /home/mysystem/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/activerecord-import-0.4.1/lib/activerecord-import/adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:48:in `post_sql_statements'
```

I'm running:

```
Rails version: 4.0.2
Ruby version: 2.0.0p643
```

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is a MySQL specific feature. The Postgres equivalent is an upsert. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT

Comment: How can I implement upsert in Rails and 'import_liks' is an array, I am trying to do a bulk insertion.

Comment: Upsert in Postgres only just arrived in 9.5. There is nothing built into rails. You would have to create the SQL query manually: `Product.import.to_sql + " ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET ..."`

Comment: @ElmiyaAgnes did you resolve it?
As I can see [here](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki/Home/90e0ea99083a5808bd06a6440bbc72f69bb2c827) [activerecord-import gem](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) supports `on_duplicate_key_update` with Postgres 9.5. But I've got the same error anyway

Comment: My Postgres version is 9.3.10

Comment: I resolved it by using upsert method with writable CTE - https://vibhorkumar.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/upsertmerge-using-writable-cte-in-postgresql-9-1/

Comment: The OP is referring to an error from activerecord-import gem.  The issue is fixed on v. 1.0.3.